# Python - How To Convert Pandas Dataframe To JSON Object?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm using `df.to_json()` to convert dataframe to json. But it gives me a json string and not an object.

How can I get JSON object?

Also, when I'm appending this data to an array, it adds single quote before and after the json and it ruins the json structure.

How can I export to json object and append properly?

**Code Used**:

```
a=[]
     array.append(df1.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)) 
     array.append(df2.to_json(orient='records', lines=True))
```

**Result**:

```
['{"test:"w","param":1}','{"test:"w2","param":2}]']
```

**Required Result**:

```
[{"test":"w","param":1},{"test":"w2","param":2}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: what you ask for is not a "json object" but a dictionary, use `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe need create dict and then convert to `json`:

```
import json
d = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
j = json.dumps(d)
```

Or if possible:

```
j = df1.to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: WHen I'm trying to append this data in to an array. It throws out this error : **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'** .  COde: **data.append(j)**

Comment: @jason - hmmm, `orient='records'` return list of `dict`, so append should working. Can you add data input sample and your code? Because I cannot simulate your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry it works but I get single quote before and after the json. Eg : **['[{"id":1,"param":"data"}]']** I don't need these single quotes when I append. How can I insert data without it?

Comment: this `'` are because `json` - `text`. so need `dictionary` for avoid it. if use `array.append(df1.to_dict(orient='records'))` it does not work?

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I append it. **[[{'test': 0, 'params': 0, 'data': 'test'}]]** Error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data**

Comment: It should have double quotes instead of single quotes I guess!

Comment: this is value in DataFrame? `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[{'test': 0, 'params': 0, 'data': 'test'}]]})`

Comment: Cool ! I got it.  **df1 = df1.fillna('')** FIxed it :)

Comment: Hi Jezreal. PLease can you look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859373/convert-all-data-within-the-json-to-csv-using-pandas-or-python     Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([{"test":"w","param":1},{"test":"w2","param":2}])
print(df)
    test  param
0     w      1
1    w2      2
```

So now we convert to a **json string**:

```
d = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(d)
'[{"test":"w","param":1},{"test":"w2","param":2}]'
```

And now we parse this string to a **list of dicts**:

```
data = json.loads(d)
print(data)
[{'test': 'w', 'param': 1}, {'test': 'w2', 'param': 2}]
```