# DataFrame to Json Using First Col as Key and Second as Value

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
k = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':['a','b','c','d']})
```

And I want to insert into a mongoDB looking like this:

```
dic = {1:'a', 2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}
```

How could I do it?

I have checked things like this but they do not seem to work on my df:

[convert pandas dataframe to json object - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384883/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-object-pandas)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly suggest you "don't" insert like that into MongoDB at all. Whilst you can store "flexible" data structures, "garbage in" is "garbage out". Anything which is a "data point" should not be used as the name of a "key" within a database. If you want meaninful queries after import on this, you really should rethink how you want to store it.

Comment: So you are suggesting not to specify index and let mongo to create one? That is a good advice and I thought about it too, but I need that to have the sctructure of : json = {key:{key:value, key:value}}

Maybe I can do it in a better way, but how?

Yes, this type may work too, right?

dic = :{1:'a', 2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}

Comment: What am saying is `{ key1: value1, key2: value2 }` IS the problem which you need to avoid. You cannot "query a database" in an efficient way to match `key1` or `key2`. `[{ k: "key1", v: "value1" },{ k: "key2", v: "value2" }]` on the other hand works just fine, since `k` and `v` are static in each element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html) and if necessary change `key` value add `rename`:

```
print (k.set_index('A').rename(columns={'B':'index1'}).to_json())
{"index1":{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d"}}
```

If need export to file:

```
k.set_index('A').rename(columns={'B':'index1'}).to_json('file.json')
```

Comment: Thank Jezrael! It is not the first time you help me!!

What about this solution?

dic = {1:'a', 2:'b',3:'c',4:'d'}

Comment: Try `print (k.set_index('A')['B'].to_json())`

Comment: That looks great mate, I am gonna test on my non-dummies df to validate!

Comment: because it is `json`, if need dict, use `print (k.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict())`

Answer (score 0):

Although what I am writing is not the answer to the question asked, still I am providing a solution to a small problem I was facing which I googled and reached here.

Problem: how to create a dictionary from a panda data frame with a column as the key and constant value (1 in my case) as the, you guessed it, value.

Solution:

```
f = pd.Series(data = [1]*df.shape[0],index=df['col_name'])
x = f.to_json(orient='columns')
```

Output:

```
{"one":1, "two":1, "three": 1}
```

Why would I do that?
Because search in the dictionary is highly optimized (Yeah I can use set as well)

P.S. Novice in Python so please be gentle with me :).