# how to convert pandas dataframe into nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is the datframe.

```
dataFrame =pd.DataFrame(['yes',10,'NaN',200703727.0,2141219]).T
dataFrame.columns=["a",'B','C','D','E']
```

DataFrame-->>

```
a   B   C   D   E
0   yes 10  NaN 2.00704e+08 2141219
```

and I want to convert this dataframe into nested JSON n rows the numbers of rows could be million in datframe.

**json output I need**

```
{   "E":2141219,
    "AA":[  {name:'a',type:'yes'},
            {name:'B',type:'10'},
            {name:'C',type:'NaN'},
            {name:'D',type:'200703727.0'}
        ]
}
```

I have to add name and type.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: That's just for  one row, what should be the output for a dataframe with more than one row? Also, what  you are asking for is a custom `JSON` which is not directly possible  with what pandas offer, so you need to take a look at `json` module in python, and convert each row manually.  You can use `dataframe.apply` then convert each row to the required json format.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to create a dictionary, or a list and then convert it to json

```
import json
dictionary = df1.to_dict(what you want to convert here)
json_1 = json.dumps
```

Comment: What did you write in the parentheses

Comment: so it can have multiple dictionaries.

Comment: I don't understand you, can you tell me what your wrote after df1.to_dict?

Comment: I only mentioned the orientation of json.

Comment: Did you put orient= before it? and it needs to be in quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)?

Also checkout:

- [Convert Pandas DataFrame to JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257147/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-format)
- [convert pandas dataframe to json object - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384883/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-object-pandas)